# Extracting from tensor using indices like numpy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor for example called tensor1 of shape (1,20,4). I am trying to create a tensor using certain indices (1,4,5) from this tensor. I could do this form numpy for example using: tensor[:,[1,4,5],:]. From what I understand this could be done using "tf.gather_nd" but I don't really see how it could be done.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `tf.slice()`. This can be used to get a certain element of a tensor. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want can be done with [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather):

```
tensor2 = tf.gather(tensor1, [1, 4, 5], axis=1)
```

Comment: @gota What is the problem that you are having? Maybe you can post a new question if this solution does not work in your case.